# Inherit from Interface only if dll is available

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, dll, interface

I have a class that is supposed to inherit from an interface only if the *.dll-file of the interface is available.

Example:

"commandInterface.dll" contains following interface:

```
public interface ICommand
{
    string GetName();
    string Run(string[] args);
}
```

"main.exe" contains following class:

```
public class TestCommand : ICommand
{
    public string GetName()
    {
        return "test";
    }
    
    public string Run(string[] args)
    {
        return args[0];
    }
}
```

That works if both files are in the same directory. Is there any way to run "main.exe" even if "commandInterface.dll" is missing? So that the class is still there, only that it no longer inherits from the interface?

Comment: This seems like a _massive_ X/Y problem. What you're asking for _fundamentally_ can't exist. What are you actually trying to do, and what path did you take to get to this implementation?

Comment: @gunr2171 I have written a program (in the following Program1), which should be able to execute certain parts from other programs (in the following ProgramX). These executable parts of ProgramX are represented as ICommand. However ProgramX should be able to be executed also if the assembly for Program1 is missing.

Comment: @Finn then make a third dll whith interface and reference it from the first two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. If the interface is missing, this won't work.